# NSTableView crash after reload

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

recently I faced the following problem.

I have a `NSTableView` with buttons in each row. Now, when clicking button, event goes to server and come back, table is reloaded with new data. So if you click button twice, quite fast but second click you hold and after releasing click table will reload because of the first event there's crash of app because of the message sent to deallocated instance of row view. I found three solutions of this crash:

1. Disable button after click and enable when table is reloaded because of the first event.
2. Change event when message is sent to button (onMouseUp to onMouseDown).
3. Keep all row views in additional array to prevent them from deallocation which is the worst one I guess because array like this grows really, really fast.

After enabling zombie objects I got this information when crash:
`[RowView performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11177d1b0`

I'm using ARC.

Has anybody of you have a better idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using completion blocks? Is your array `nonatomic`?

Comment: Yes for both questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would not allow users to interfere while table is already being loaded with earlier call. I would go with your #1 choice.

Comment: But shouldn't the reference be kept unrealeased since the user clicked the view? Is it bug of cocoa that it is deallocated before sending message to a view?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Could you please run with exception break point to find out the root cause. This is definitely code issue and not cocoa bug.